# How to use specific proxy address for specific application in Windows XP?

Tags: windows, proxy, ip, network-protocols

I have a chat client application. When I connect to internet & chat with other person via that application, the application uses the IP of my ISP to connect to internet & transfers data via that IP. Can I use a specific proxy address such:(50.17.156.80:3128) to force that chat application to connect to internet & to transfer data via this IP ?

Here This is the IP: 50.17.156.80 & this is the port: 3128

Note that: If we want, we can use proxy address in our browser to connect to internet.

So, can i use the same system for the chat application so that it will transfer data via that proxy IP ? If yes, Please tell me how ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use http://www.proxycap.com/ this allows you to add a program, and apply a rule to specific proxy

Comment: Ah, good old memories. Was using this years ago to tunnel online games via a specific route for a lower ping.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if the chat application has option to to use a proxy in its settings. If not , you can use the proxy server using proxify (http://proxify.com/launchpad.shtml) or similar applications.

or you can set up a vpn connection which is more secure .